# Using hook value in promise chain

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to figure out how I can use the state value from a hook in a function. At the moment, I am able to use the value when the component is returned, but within my function it is appearing as `undefined`. Is there a limit to the scope of where state values can be accessed? I am trying to use this value as a workaround to the limitation in passing values down promise chains so I can check if a redirect should be triggered

**Undefined line:**

`console.log(message) // undefined`

**Function where `message` is accessed:**

```
const signIn = (e) => {
        
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Axios: signIn Triggered')
        axios.post('/api/auth/signin/', { email, password }, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            withCredentials: true
        }).then((res) => {
            console.log('Success - res')
            console.log(res)
            const data = res.data;
            console.log(data.message)
            console.log(data.user)
            console.log(message)
            // Set user session state with returned user data
            setUser(data.user)
            setMessage(data.message)
        }).then(()=> {
            // On successful sigin, redirect to /app/profile/

            console.log(message) // returns `undefined`
            
            // if (message.status !== 'error'){
                // router.push('/app/profile/')
            // }
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
            console.log(err.request)
            console.log(err.message)
        })
    }
```

**Full Code:**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { SessionContext }  from '../../../contexts/AppSession'

const SignInForm = () => {
    const [{ email, password }, setForm] = useState({ email: null, password: null })
    const [message, setMessage] = useState()
    const { user, setUser } = useContext(SessionContext) // here you are calling a hook at component body
    const router = useRouter()

    const handleChange = ({ target }) => {
        setForm( prevForm => ({
        ...prevForm,
        [target.name]: target.value
        }));
    }

    const signIn = (e) => {
        
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Axios: signIn Triggered')
        axios.post('/api/auth/signin/', { email, password }, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            withCredentials: true
        }).then((res) => {
            console.log('Success - res')
            console.log(res)
            const data = res.data;
            console.log(data.message)
            console.log(data.user)
            console.log(message)
            // Set user session state with returned user data
            setUser(data.user)
            setMessage(data.message)
        }).then(()=> {
            // On successful sigin, redirect to /app/profile/
            console.log(message)
            
            // if (message.status !== 'error'){
                // router.push('/app/profile/')
            // }
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
            console.log(err.request)
            console.log(err.message)
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(user)
    }, [user]) // with that console.log will run on every user change

    return (
        <div className="signup-form">
            <div className="grid min-h-screen place-items-center">
                <div className="w-11/12 p-12 bg-white sm:w-8/12 md:w-1/2 lg:w-5/12">
                    <h1 className="text-xl font-semibold">Hello there , <span className="font-normal">please fill in your information to continue</span></h1>
                    <form className="mt-6" action="/api/auth/signin/" method="post">
                        <label htmlFor="email" className="block mt-2 text-xs font-semibold text-gray-600 uppercase">E-mail</label>
                        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="john.doe@company.com" autoComplete="email" className="block w-full p-3 mt-2 text-gray-700 bg-gray-200 appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-300 focus:shadow-inner" value={ email || '' } onChange={ handleChange } required />
                        <label htmlFor="password" className="block mt-2 text-xs font-semibold text-gray-600 uppercase">Password</label>
                        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="********" autoComplete="new-password" className="block w-full p-3 mt-2 text-gray-700 bg-gray-200 appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-300 focus:shadow-inner" value={ password || '' } onChange={ handleChange } required />
                        <button type="submit" className="w-full py-3 mt-6 font-medium tracking-widest text-white uppercase bg-black shadow-lg focus:outline-none hover:bg-gray-900 hover:shadow-none" onClick={ signIn }>
                            Sign In
                        </button>
                        {message ?
                        <div className="bg-red-200 px-6 py-4 my-4 rounded-md text-lg flex items-center w-full">
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" className="text-red-600 w-10 h-10 sm:w-5 sm:h-5 mr-3">
                                <path fill="currentColor" d="M11.983,0a12.206,12.206,0,0,0-8.51,3.653A11.8,11.8,0,0,0,0,12.207,11.779,11.779,0,0,0,11.8,24h.214A12.111,12.111,0,0,0,24,11.791h0A11.766,11.766,0,0,0,11.983,0ZM10.5,16.542a1.476,1.476,0,0,1,1.449-1.53h.027a1.527,1.527,0,0,1,1.523,1.47,1.475,1.475,0,0,1-1.449,1.53h-.027A1.529,1.529,0,0,1,10.5,16.542ZM11,12.5v-6a1,1,0,0,1,2,0v6a1,1,0,1,1-2,0Z"></path>
                            </svg>
                            <span class="text-red-800">{ message.body }</span>
                        </div>
                            : null
                        }
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SignInForm;
```

Comment: you getting `undefined` in next then because you not returning anything in previous `then`

Comment: I think OP is assuming that the second `.then` is being executed after `setMessage`. (though I agree your suggestion will solve the immediate problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not forget that arrow function always remember values in a moment the function was created... So in the beginning your `message` value is `undefined` and it will remain undefined till the moment the component will be rerender, so when you call `setMessage` it doesn't influence message value at all, it just gives a command to react that you'd like to change the state...

so if you want to see new value in next `then` block after `setMessage(data.message)` just return data.message and read it as a parameter in your next block

```
  setMessage(data.message)
  return data.message
}).then(newMessage => {
  // On successful sigin, redirect to /app/profile/
  console.log(newMessage)
```